# Screenshot file resize script or app

Tags: script, images, screenshot

Windows 10. 
Taking screenshots via "X-keys programmable usb keypad". 
These are stored in a specific folder. 
Later we add these screenshots to a report that is sent via e-mail.

Problem is; we are talking 10-20-30 pictures and with the relatively big file sizes, we can't send them via e-mail.

We can't edit them on the go, only at the end of the day. Image resize online works pretty well at reducing file size without losing too much quality. But it's cumbersome and we don't always have good internet connection. Here is the question ;

We need a way to batch resize the images easily and fast. Several different people will use this computer, so "easy" is key. What is the best way ?

A standalone image resize application? 
Is there some script you can run i.e "reduce all images in folder "xxx" to 50% size" ?

Comment: Adding to the duplicate, there are screenshot utilities that allow the creation of workflows that could automate the resizing process.

Comment: Can't your mail client do the resizing on the fly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v4Tw.png

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool you can use via you're browser (no upload of the pictures needed): https://www.bulkresizephotos.com/

It allows you to resize your pictures (the resolution) thus making them smaller.

Pro:

- simple through drag&drop
- no installation needed
- independent from the operating system you use

Cons:

- internet connection needed (but only for loading the page not for resizing the pictures

Another one which requires an upload:
https://www.iloveimg.com/resize-image